# What are all of the ways to obtain upgrade points?

Tags: destiny-2

In Destiny 1, as you gained experience, your sub-classes advanced as well to allow you to unlock new abilities. In Destiny 2, they changed this to where you use upgrade points in order to unlock new abilities.

I started out as a Warlock, which begins you off with the Dawnblade sub-classes, but unfortunately, without realizing that the Stormcaller sub-classes isn't unlocked until later, I spent every upgrade point so far. Now I am wanting to save my upgrade points until I unlock Stormcaller, but I am also wanting to advance in the other sub-classes afterwards.

Based on [this article](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/destiny-2-psa-dont-spend-all-your-upgrade-points-i/1100-6453146/), it mentions there are a multiple ways to getting upgrade points, but it doesn't go into detail of every possible way

> Upgrade Points are earned in a variety of ways, including completing Adventures, but the easiest way is by leveling up

What are all of the ways to obtain upgrade points to advance in your sub-classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ways as far as I can tell: (After maxing my warlock subclasses)

**1)** Leveling up, you'll continue to earn them this way past 20 until you've filled out all the skills in a class.

**2)** Doing adventures that have upgrade points as a reward. If you've fully upgrading each subclass these rewards will change, usually into blue engrams in my experience.

**3)** If you do meditations and still need upgrade points you can get them from those.

Comment: After a few days of playing destiny, this does appear to be the only two ways of obtaining upgrade points. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I was wrong. Once you complete the main story, you can do mediation missions from Ikora which gives you upgrade points as rewards.

Comment: That's if you have them available or need them

Comment: yeah, just informing so you can edit your answer :)